# UpdateSourceTrigger not working when TextBox becomes empty

Tags: c#, wpf

I have following XAML -

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=NumberOfItems, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" />
<Button Command="{Binding Path=StartCommand}">Start</Button>
```

In ViewModel -

```
public string this[string columnName]
    {
        get
        {
            string result = null;
            switch (columnName)
            {
                 case "NumberOfItems":
                    if (this.NumberOfItems <= 0)
                    {
                        result = "Items required";
                    }
                    break;
            }

            return result;
        }
    }
```

Whenever, TextBox changes values the trigger works accordingly. But in following cases, It is not working -

1. When user presses delete button in keyboard after selecting whole text of textbox.
2. When user deletes the last character present in TextBox.

however ValidatesOnDataError is working.

How can I make it work when TextBox empties?

When user enters any invalid data, TextBox Style changes. I want this to be known in click of Start Button.

How can I make aware the Start button that TextBox has invalid data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When user enters any invalid data, TextBox Style changes. I want this to be known in click of Start Button.
>
> How can I make aware the Start button that TextBox has invalid data?

change your validation code to:

```
 case "NumberOfItems":
                if (this.NumberOfItems==null || this.NumberOfItems <= 0)
                {
                    result = "Items required";
                }
                break;
```

You can check `string.IsNullOrEmpty(this["NumberOfItems"])` within the `CanExceuteStartCommand` of your `StartCommand`

Comment: I tried your solution, but same thing is happening. When TextBox empties, Its style changes, however        string.IsNullOrEmpty(this["NumberOfItems"])       results always true

Comment: @user2039445: have you added `TargetNullValue={x:Static sys:String.Empty}` in your binding as @Manish stated?

Answer (score 4):

I am guessing you are trying to Bind a property of type integer to the text property of your textbox. Since integers cannot be null, empty string will not work in this case. You can use either nullable integer or you can create your own converter to handle empty string.

Comment: You are right. I have made it nullable, but it is not working.

Comment: Try this Text="{Binding Path=NumberOfItems, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, TargetNullValue={x:Static sys:String.Empty}, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"                                            You will have to add the namespace  xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"

Comment: Thanks Manish, Text="{Binding Path=NumberOfItems, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, TargetNullValue={x:Static sys:String.Empty}, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"    worked!